# I need that if the pathname matches with the arrays name, a group of photos is visible while the others groups are not

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router, swiper.js

```
export default function Gallery() {
  const [projectsData, setProjectsData] = useState(projects);
    
  let location = useLocation();
    
  const swiperNavPrevRef = useRef();
  const swiperNavNextRef = useRef();
    
  const photos = ['archfosil.jpeg', 'MVI_1419.MP4']
    
  const photos2 = ['IMG_0753.MOV']
        
  return (
    <>
      <GalleryStyle>
        <div className="galleryitems">
          <Swiper
            modules={[Navigation]}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: swiperNavPrevRef.current,
              nextEl: swiperNavNextRef.current,
            }}
            style={{ "--swiper-theme-color":"#fff", }}
            speed={800}
            slidesPerView={1}
            loop
            className="myswiper"
          >
            <div className="swiperNavPrev" ref={swiperNavPrevRef}></div>
            <div className="swiperNavNext" ref={swiperNavNextRef}></div>
            {photos.map((photo, i) =>
              <SwiperSlide className="swiperslide">
                <img src={require(`../assets/images/${photo.toString()}`)} alt="" />
              </SwiperSlide>
            )}
            {photos2.map((photo, i) =>
              <SwiperSlide className="swiperslide">
                <img src={require(`../assets/images/${photo.toString()}`)} alt="" />
              </SwiperSlide>
            )}
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </GalleryStyle>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
const projects = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    id2: 1,
    name: 'project 1',
    desc:
      'description.',
    img: image1,
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    id2: 2,
    name: 'project 2',
    desc:
      'yes.',
    img: img2,
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    id2: 3,
    name: 'project 3',
    desc:
      'Non Yeet.',
    img: image3,
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    id2: 4,
    name: "project 4",
    desc:
      'Non yet.',
    img: image4,
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    id2: 5,
    name: 'project 5',
    desc:
      'None yet.',
    img: image5,
  },
];

export default projects;
```

I made that if you click one of the project displayed yo go to the path (example.com/gallery/$name of the project listed like 'project 1').

Inside `Gallery`, I made object "photos" & "photos2", depending on the pathname we are in. If we are in (example.com/gallery/project%1) I wanted to use `filter()` and if I called projects using projectsData, and if it matched the name inside projects with the pathname, it would made visible "photos" images while "photos2" remain hide.

I did thought of everything more complex that it shall be? I tried a bunch of ways but it seems that everyone fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest coupling the photo arrays to the routes versus trying to programmatically compute which route you are on. In fact, `react-router` ***already*** does this part for you. Render each project on a route that renders the `Gallery` component and pass the photo array as a prop.

Example:

```
export default function Gallery({ photos = [] }) {
  const [projectsData, setProjectsData] = useState(projects);
    
  const swiperNavPrevRef = useRef();
  const swiperNavNextRef = useRef();
    
  return (
    <GalleryStyle>
      <div className="galleryitems">
        <Swiper
          modules={[Navigation]}
          navigation={{
            prevEl: swiperNavPrevRef.current,
            nextEl: swiperNavNextRef.current,
          }}
          style={{ "--swiper-theme-color": "#fff" }}
          speed={800}
          slidesPerView={1}
          loop
          className="myswiper"
        >
          <div className="swiperNavPrev" ref={swiperNavPrevRef} />
          <div className="swiperNavNext" ref={swiperNavNextRef} />
          {photos.map((photo) =>
            <SwiperSlide key={photo} className="swiperslide">
              <img
                src={require(`../assets/images/${photo.toString()}`)} 
                alt=""
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
          )}
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </GalleryStyle>
  );
}
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="gallery">
    <Route
      path="project%1"
      element={<Gallery photos={['archfosil.jpeg', 'MVI_1419.MP4']} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="project%2"
      element={<Gallery photos={['IMG_0753.MOV']} />}
    />
    ... etc ...

  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: This is pretty amazing and it worked flawless, however I did got the link like this `Link to={`/gallery/${title}/${id2} `}` and I have tried doing something like `<Route path="/:id*/2" 
          element={<Gallery photos={['IMG_0130.jpeg']} />}
          >
            <Gallery />`    But it's not showing the image, anyway everything else cleaned my spaghetti code, thank you again =)

Comment: @Tontito `path="/:id*/2"` isn't a valid path, the wildcard character `"*"` is only valid at the end of a path to allow a component to render descendent routes and have them be matchable. Can you clarify what the issue is with your links (*if you are saying there is one*), I was just guessing at your route structure?

Comment: You have been very helpful I will try my very best to find the problem, I cannot give a very wide code here but I'll use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EeaH1B3h) These are the main trouble maker renders, I don't know If I forced too much and made it harder than it shall be. The main trouble is that I cannot visualize the images per group as I made the example of before. I applied your solution before, it worked flawless but then when I tried again I couldn't. If it's a lot I'm really sorry, anyone who wants to use it for it's own or apply in his own code feel free. –

Comment: @Tontito I am unsure what you mean by "wide code", and the pastebin link doesn't appear to be working for me. Can you try creating a *minimal, running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. And I hope you had a nice Christmas as I did. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-diffie-smmwlb) This is the demo which is not working at all but in my code is just not displaying the images.

Comment: @Tontito Remove the `.default` from the images you are trying to render. Here's a fork of your sandbox with the routes fixed up and the images rendering. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-water-bnxk5f?file=/src/pages/Gallery.js

Comment: Even with all my wrong expressions you helped me a lot !! Yes, it is working and thanks to you glad the code works smooth and fine. Thank you a lot !